# Unable to set up POST method route in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, rest, http-headers, cakephp-1.2

I've set up the following route in CakePHP 1.2:

```
Router::connect(
    "/inbound/:hash",
    array('controller' => 'profiles', 'action' => 'inbound', '[method]' => 'POST'),
    array('hash' => '[0-9a-zA-Z]+'),
    array('pass' => array('hash'))
);
```

Here are my request headers (via drupal_http_request()):

```
POST /inbound HTTP/1.0
Host: mysite.dev
User-Agent: Drupal (+http://drupal.org/)
Content-Length: 45

hash=test
```

However, I'm getting a 404 in response when I post. If I remove the parameter ":hash" from my route definition I get a 200. But in both cases the action in my controller does not get the passed parameter (hash).

I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong, as I appear to be doing [what is in the doc](http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/view/478/Custom-REST-Routing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the `pass` parameter is to define which route parameters are being passed to the action. So what you are doing there is creating a route that connects to URLs like this:

```
/inbound/foo
```

where `foo` would be passed as a parameter to the controllers `inbound` action.

Your request however points to `/inbound` only, so this won't match your route as the parameter is missing, and consequently you are receiving a 404.

The data in the body of your POST request is being passed as regular POST data, ie it would be available via the controllers `params` property:

```
$this->params['form']['hash']
```

So either remove the `hash` parameter in the route and access the data via `$this->params['form']`, or pass the data in the URL where the `hash` parameter is defined:

```
/inbound/test
```

then you can access it in your controller action like this:

```
function inbound($hash)
{
    echo $hash;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, when I drop the pass element from the route $this->params['form'] is an empty array.

Comment: It works fine as described. What does your route now look like? When dropping the parameter from the URL it should be like this: `Router::connect("/inbound", array('controller' => 'profiles', 'action' => 'inbound', '[method]' => 'POST'));`

Comment: Oh man, totally my bad. Sorry. I was using a Drupal API function to make the POST request, but a more low-level cURL request works just fine. If you edit the question, I will up vote.